# Not able to install deploy to container plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

i am not able to install deploy to container plugin in jenkins.

[image]

Comment: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:284)
 at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:345)
 at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133)

Comment: Internet connection?